# Why does the Java compiler not like primitive int as type for values in HashMap?

Tags: java, types, integer, hashmap

The compiler complains about this code:

```
    HashMap<String,int> userName2ind = new HashMap<String,int>();
    for (int i=0; i<=players.length; i++) {
        userName2ind.put(orderedUserNames[i],i+1);
    }
```

It writes "unexpected type" and point on `int`. If I replace `int` by `String` and `i+1` by `i+"1"`, the compilation goes OK. What is wrong with in here?

Comment: Doesn't i+"1" ends up being "01" for i==0; "11" for i==1 etc?

Comment: Yes. i+"1" ends up being "01" for i==0 and so on.

Comment: googling "java hashmap int" points to many references that already have asked/ solved this issue. Research your question first.

Comment: Simple answer: generics, long answer: java generics are weird and don't actually exist (it's all compiler trickery) so ints are a nono.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It's fine with `Integer`, but not okay with `int` - [Java generics only work with reference types](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html), basically :(

Try this - although be aware it will box everything:

```
HashMap<String,Integer> userName2ind = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for (int i=0; i<=players.length; i++) {
    userName2ind.put(orderedUserNames[i],i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have small collections, then using reference types is probably fine, but there are alternatives and good one is [trove4j](http://trove.starlight-systems.com/). Trove does a pretty good job of recreating the collections API using pure primitives. The payoff is *much* lower memory usage and in many cases, better performance when inserting/looking up. Your example would look like this:

```
TObjectIntHashMap<String> userName2ind = new TObjectIntHashMap<String>();
for (int i=0; i<=players.length; i++) {
    userName2ind.put(orderedUserNames[i],i+1);
}
```

The only downside, in my experience, is the absence of concurrent implementations of these, so you have to figure out another way to manage thread safety.