# Getting Int from EditText causes error?

Tags: android, android-edittext, int

So first of all sorry if this has already been asked and answered before, I couldn't find anything relating to my issue.

So I'm working on a project for college and I need to get int values from EditText widgets. I was told to use parseInt to do this however when running my program, that line of code causes the application to crash. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I'm still very new to android development, thanks for the help :)

```
public void Calculate (View view)
{
    int MilesTravelled;
    int FuelUsed;
    int MPG;

    /* the two lines below are what cause the application to crash */

    MilesTravelled = Integer.parseInt(txtMilesTravelled.getText().toString());
    FuelUsed = Integer.parseInt(txtFuelUsed.getText().toString());

    FuelUsed = (int) (FuelUsed / 4.55);
    MPG = MilesTravelled / FuelUsed; 
    lblMPG.setText(FuelUsed); 
}
```

Comment: Could you write the output of the logcat?

Comment: I cannot, I'm unable to run the app in virtual developer and eclipse doesnt detect my tablet, so I have to copy the apk to my device and run like that

Comment: You can not create a emulator?

Comment: Nope, no idea why but the emulator just doesnt work on my laptop. I'll try again though. (it loads up put the screen stays black)

Comment: Then is hard to tell what may be the error. You have initialized the edittext with `findviewbyid`?

Comment: You should really try to get emulator & logcat working, before you debug your app.

Comment: yeah I have, just trying to run the emulator now, still no luck.

Comment: Error might be in this line : lblMPG.setText(FuelUsed); Wrote an answer, see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this in the onCreate() function?

```
 EditText txtMilesTravelled = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.YourEditText);
```

But I think you mixed `Integer` and `int`. They are not the same:

[See this link!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474576/java-primitive-types-int-vs-integer)

Comment: Ah and you should make the int to a string before you set the text here: lblMPG.setText(FuelUsed.toString());

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't capitalize the first letter of an variables or method names. Following the Java coding conventions, only do that for classes.

What is probably causing your app to crash is you trying to set the text of a label to an integer. The `setText` method for a TextView needs to take in a string.

So change:

```
lblMPG.setText(FuelUsed);
```

to:

```
lblMPG.setText(String.valueOf(FuelUsed));
```

---

Otherwise it might be that it's trying to parse a non-numerical string to an integer.
For exmaple, if the EditText is blank, it will cause your app to crash. To prevent that, try this:

```
int MilesTravelled = 0, FuelUsed = 0;
try {

    MilesTravelled = Integer.parseInt(txtMilesTravelled.getText().toString());
    FuelUsed = Integer.parseInt(txtFuelUsed.getText().toString());

} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error NFE!", 0).show();
    nfe.printStackTrace();
}
```

This way, it will catch a NumberFormatException error (parsing a string to an integer that can't be represented as an integer, such as "hello"). If it catches the error, it will toast that an error has occurred and your integer variables will remain 0.

---

Or you could just test if the strings contain only digits using the following regex:

```
int MilesTravelled = 0, FuelUsed = 0;

if (txtMilesTravelled.getText().toString().matches("[0-9]+")) {
    MilesTravelled = Integer.parseInt(txtMilesTravelled.getText().toString());
} else {
    // contains characters that are not digits
}
if (txtFuelUsed.getText().toString().matches("[0-9]+")) {
    FuelUsed = Integer.parseInt(txtFuelUsed.getText().toString());
} else {
    // contains characters that are not digits
}
```

---

**If that's not the problem,** then make sure you define your variables properly.

`txtMilesTravelled` and `txtFuelUsed` should be `EditText`:

```
EditText txtMilesTravelled = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMilesTravelled);
EditText txtFuelUsed = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFuelUsed);
```

And make sure that your `R.id.editText` actually exists on your layout and that the IDs are the correct ones.

---

Last thing, make sure `FuelUsed` is not 0 before calculating `MPG` because then you are dividing by 0:

```
int MPG = 0;

if (FuelUsed != 0) {
    MPG = MilesTravelled / FuelUsed; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you're entering perfect integers in the `EditTexts`. It might be a good idea to use the `trim` function `txtMilesTravelled.getText().toString().trim()` before using `parseInt`.

However, I think the major problem is here : `lblMPG.setText(FuelUsed);` 
`FuelUsed` is an integral value, when you pass an integer to `setText()`, it looks for a string resource with that integral value. So you should be passing a String to the `setText()` method.

Use :     `lblMPG.setText(Integer.toString(FuelUsed));`