# Is it better to annotate Integer with @NonNull, or use primitive int?

Tags: java, android

Say you have a method called 'setFloorNumber' that takes an integer that can't be null.
Two different ways I figured you could do this:

```
public void setFloorNumber (@NonNull Integer floor){
   ...
}
```

or

```
public void setFloorNumber (int floor){
   ...
}
```

Best I can tell, they both accomplish the same thing which is requiring the integer parameter to not be null.

What are the pros and cons for these?

Is there a reason to want to choose one over the other, or are the differences negligible enough that it's purely just a stylistic choice?

Comment: Usually this is not something you need to handle. If someone incorrectly uses `setFloorNumber()` with a null Integer, just let a `NullPointerException` be thrown. Seems appropriate to me.

Comment: You should look into [use cases for primitive int and Integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474576/java-primitive-types-int-vs-integer) , since you should prefer int over Integer unless necessary, same goes for this scenario.

Comment: In general you should prefer `int` unless you have a really good reason to use `Integer` (such as storing numbers in a `List` or other container). One reason is to avoid unnecessary boxing and unboxing.

Answer (score 0):

You are actually using two separate types.

If you use `int` than you cannot have a null value, it is a primitive type and it must be initialized to something, for instance `int myNumber = 0;` if you use an Integer, you are actually creating an Integer object. This is usually unnecessary and could be avoided.