# Benefits of using wrapper classes over primitives in Java

Tags: java, wrapper

At a very abstract level I do know that wrapper classes, create an object of the primitive data type but I was curious as to why do we need to use wrapper classes and what benefits do they offer over primitive data types.

Comment: You can take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570416/when-to-use-wrapper-class-and-primitive-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509025/when-to-use-primitive-and-when-reference-types-in-java

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Collections in the first place, for example,`List<Integer>`, you cannot use primitive `int` here.
Actually any generic class / interface that can work with different object types like

```
public interface Callable<V> {
    V call() throws Exception;
}
```

Note that wrapping is best done using not new Integer(i) but Integer.valueOf(i) the latter will try to use cache. Unwrapping is done as Integer.intValue(). These wrapping / unwrapping of primitives are so typical operations that Java 5 introduced autoboxing / unboxing

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(1);
int i = list.get(0);
```

this code is automatically converted by Java compiler into

```
list.add(Integer.valueIf(1));
int i = list.get(0).intValue();    // this is where NullPointerException sometimes happens
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrapper classes are designed to add more functionality to the primitive types, so that they are compatible with generic code, using the Collection Framework, and many other benefits. However, they are not mean't to **replace** primitive types.

So, you should use wrappers only when necessary, such as when dealing with generics, because creating an object adds substantial overheads to your program. So, in normal cases, you should stick to primitives.

Answer (score 1):

A wrapper type enables a primitive to hold more contextual meaning. For instance an integer could be anything, whereas a class called Hours, for example, gives the number meaning wherever it is used.

They also enable methods to be written that mutate the said primitive in a consistent and obvious way to consumers. Have a look at [Domain Driven Design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) for more information surrounding this point.

Comment: So would it suffice to say that wrapper does not offer any better performance over primitive data type, 
it only adds contextual meaning to a data type ?

Answer (score 0):

The primitive types just hold value, the wrapper class gives it a name.

With a class name, the compiler can do some static check for you. It makes the interface more meaningful. And you can also defined some method in wrapper classes to validate the primitive values.

Normally, for a small project, i think use primitive types is just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Wrapper objects are normal objects and there references can be `null`. This allows the usage of a "not set" state which is impossible with primitives.

```
Integer no = null;    // not set
```

You have to use a magic value like -1 to indicate that a primitive variable is "unset".

Answer (score 0):

Just imagine : your playing a game in that you need to save the status and you want to play in different computer(same game) then u decided to take status (level) to the other computer then you can continue from that state(not from the beginning).. Okay come to the questions if your current weapons status is 3. like {  int weapons=1; if(you add weapons by playing some levels okay now its 3) } but you cannot able to store it as object because primitives are different.(lives in stack). so you need weapons as objects (( solution : create Integer Object))
Integer weapon = new Integer(1){ ...  }