# Java: trouble with Scanner / ArrayList types

Tags: java, arraylist, types

Context: I'm very new to coding. I'm writing a text-based singleplayer RPG as a learning method.

So, I have an ArrayList that I'm using to store objects of the class Item. I want to check the ArrayList for the existence of an item (object from the Item class) based on user input from a Scanner.

If possible, I think it would be cleaner if I passed in an Item to the switch (based on user input) rather than a string that I later have to "translate" for the ArrayList to work with it.

Is that possible? Or do I have to do it in the way that I have written out in the following code? Or is there a better, entirely different way to go about it that I don't know of?

```
public class Test{

//New Array that will store a player's items like an inventory

static ArrayList<Item> newInvTest = new ArrayList<>();

//Placing a test item into the player's inventory array
//The arguments passed in to the constructor are the item's name (as it would be displayed to the player) and number of uses

static Item testWand = new Item("Test Wand", 5);

//Method for when the player wants to interact with an item in their inventory

public static void useItem(){
    System.out.print("Which item do you wish to use?\n: ");
    Scanner scanner5 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String itemChoice = scanner5.nextLine();
    itemChoice = itemChoice.toLowerCase();
    switch (itemChoice){
        case "testwand":
        case "test wand":
        boolean has = newInvTest.contains(testWand);
        if(has == true){
            //the interaction occurs
        }else{ 
            System.out.println("You do not possess this item: " + itemChoice);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: How about using a HashMap instead?

Comment: You can override the `equals `of the `Item`.

Comment: The title is not clear, the problem is with type in switch....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The type of the Expression must be char, byte, short, int, Character, Byte, Short, Integer, String, or an enum type (§8.9), or a compile-time error occurs.

From http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.11

That means you can't pass the item itself into the switch. However, if you want to have readable code, maybe for your other team members, if you were working in a group, then you could employ a hashmap and enum for the switch.

For instance:

```
public enum ItemChoice {
    SWORD, WAND, CAT
}
```

And then for the hashmap

```
HashMap<String, ItemChoice> choice = new HashMap<String, ItemChoice>();
```

Then you load the hashmap with the values you would expect, such as:

```
choice.put("Wand", ItemChoice.WAND)
```

Then you could easily get an enum value from the user input and then use it in your switch. It is more extensive than you current approach of checking for Strings, but it is more readable and you could call it "cleaner."

If you are going with your current approach, checking with Strings. Then I would suggest you remove the " " empty spaces from the String **itemChoice** so you don't have you do to cases, such as:

```
case "testwand":
case "test wand":
```

but instead you would only need one case

```
case "testwand":
```

This is not really affecting anything, but since you do not use the boolean has again, then you could do this

```
if(newInvTest.contains(testWand)){
    // the interaction occurs
    // boolean has is not needed anymore!
}
```

And a suggestion for the future, you might want to create a Player object, that way you can hold the ArrayList in the player object, rather than a static variable. Also, it would allow you to easily save data from the player more easily, such as amount of money the player has, number of kills, level number, etc... It is just better to try to adhere to object orientated programming.

So for example you would have:

```
public class Player {

    private ArrayList<Item> newInvTest = new ArrayList<>();

    private String name;

    private int currentLevel;

    public String getName(){
        return name
    }

    public int getCurrentLevel(){
        return currentLevel
    }

    public ArrayList<Item> getInventory(){
        return newInvTest;
    }

}
```

So if you wanted to get the inventory, you can reference to an instance variable, rather than a static variable. It makes more sense to assign these variables to a Player object, since they belong to the player. So you could get the inventory like this:

```
player.getInventory();
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how saving data works, and how having the player as an object of a class (rather than a class with static variables as I have it now) would help?

Comment: If you mean data saving for the player attributes. I have posted an explanation on how a Player class would help organize and hold different values. You might also want to read the: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284246/is-there-a-reason-to-always-use-objects-instead-of-primitives