# How can I convert a above 16 digit string to integer in java?

Tags: java, int, numberformatexception

i Am beginner of java. pls help me,

```
int i = Integer.parseInt("9876543210123456");
System.out.println("Integer: " + i);
```

i got below error,

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException for input string : "9876543210123456"
```

Comment: The maximal value of an Integer is 2^32 -1, this is way above that. Use a `BigInteger` instead

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSP (even if you are experiencing the problem in a JSP).  It is all about `int`.

Comment: Is `numberformatexception` really a tag worth adding? It's not as though anyone actually follows it.

Comment: So, so many tags are essentially useless. Yet they are kept alive by new users tagging every keyword in their question.

Comment: @ChrisHayes  Of course it is, if only for grouping questions and finding duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

It's crossing the integer limit , You need [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/class-use/BigInteger.html)

```
BigInteger b = new BigInteger("9876543210123456");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't convert the above value to an `int`, as it exceeds Integer's max value: 2,147,483,647.

Instead try:

```
Long.parseLong("9876543210123456");
```

Long has a maximum value of 9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

To check the maximum values of these and other primitive data types try:

```
Integer.MAX_VALUE;
Long.MAX_VALUE;
// etc for Float, Double...
// Also try MIN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, the primitive int data type is a 32-bit signed two's complement integer
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

You can use Long:

```
long i = Long.parseLong("9876543210123456");
System.out.println("Long: " + i);
```

Refer to the API here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html

Or you can also use BigInteger:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("9876543210123456");
System.out.println("BigInteger: " + i);
```

Refer to the API here - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

BigInteger is analogous to the primitive integer types except that it provides arbitrary precision, hence operations on BigIntegers do not overflow or lose precision. In addition to standard arithmetic operations, BigInteger provides modular arithmetic, GCD calculation, primality testing, prime generation, bit manipulation, and a few other miscellaneous operations.

If you are confused whether to use a primitive or an object reference, here is a good discussion

[When to use primitive and when reference types in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509025/when-to-use-primitive-and-when-reference-types-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

In java range of int is from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. So try long instead of int.

Answer (score 0):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

You can also use a NumberFormat to parse numbers:

```
 myNumber = nf.parse("9876543210123456");
```

see below

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Although BigInteger might work, but the best way is to keep it `String` only and display it as `String`. That's the ideal way for dealing with long digit numbers and you won't end up with any type of exceptions.

Comment: Then how will you perform arithmetic operations?

Comment: That's the secondary case. As per reading the question, if the resulting value exceeds the `MAX_INT` value, why not keep it String only and display(on console or webpage or any other).

Answer (score -1):

```
long x = Long.parseLong("9876543210123456");

System.out.println("Integer: " + x);
```

or else ple use follow line

```
BigInteger bint = new BigInteger("9999999999999999", 16);
```

Please try this..Can't avle to convert the more than 13 digits string to int..so,you should convert to long