# Why use int instead of Integer (or the other way around) in Java?

Tags: java, integer

I know that `Integer` is a class and `int` is just a number, but when should we use one over another and how to convert `Integer` to `int` (and vice versa)?

** Also, there is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509025/when-to-use-primitive-and-when-reference-types-in-java)
question (what is autoboxing by the way) but I am asking **WHEN** to use int over Integer in actual programming (such as performance issues, ease of use and readability) and vice versa and not the **DIFFERENCE** between them.

Comment: take look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8660691/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-int-in-java

Comment: "how to convert Integer to int (and vice versa)" - any decent Java tutorial and the Javadocs provide that information. Look at the `Integer` class specifically.

Comment: My recommendation is the same as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570425